# How to create more than one weblogic domain on one machine (LocalHost)

Tags: windows, weblogic, multiple-domains

I am new to Oracle Weblogic and need to create 2 *Oracle WebLogic 12.1.3* domains on my local **Windows** machine in port 7001 and 7002.
I read some articles about WebLogic, but none of them refers to creating more than one domain on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by having different port assigned to your second domain's admin server and a different domain home.

If you are running config.sh/config.cmd to create domain, ensure that you give different port than 7001 for your admin server and a different domain home and domain name.

If you have created second domain with default admin port i.e 7001, still no problem. You can always have different port configured on similar lines.

```
<server>
    <name>AdminServer</name>
    <listen-port>8001</listen-port>
```

Please note that the path of the admin server can't be changed once configured. Running config.sh/config.cmd again is the only approach in this case.
Keep this thread updated with your outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create while creating using the UI you can mentioned a different port (7002). with the script you can mentioned the 7002 port.
I once created an admin server running at 7001 port and the managed server running at 8001 port.

As long as your machine has enough resources to provide. This should work fine.